Fetch without following redirect and opaque response
Is it possible to use fetch() without following redirects and without an opaque response?
Problem: I want to send a request and not follow an unnecessary redirect (302). I also want to know if the request succeeded by checking that the response status is 302 (and not 5xx for example), but the redirect option for requests seems to allow only following, erroring, or making opaque requests with redirect: "manual" as in the code below.
let request = new Request("/submit", {
  redirect: "manual"
});

fetch(request)
  .then((response) => {
    console.debug("Response status was " + response.status); // always 0 with redirect: "manual"
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

In other words I want to detect redirects, not follow them.

Is a dummy HEAD request acceptable?

@Kaiido HEAD request seems to also be unaware of the redirect, it also seem to always get type: "opaqueredirect" with status: 0 in redirect: "manual" request mode or throw without useful information in redirect: "error" request mode. Can you make it report 302s?

Not really between a 301 and a 302, but if you let it as follow, then you'll get the .redirected prop set to true (you could also check if the .url is the same).

@Kaiido I see, it on one hand does not fulfil the not follow [redirects] request OP had, but OTOH it is fact that such body-less response showing final (un)success is most probably what they really need. It provides info that some redirect happened, final URL and status. Now most important question is whether their target systems accept HEAD. (I've seen few severs configured to refuse them, what is obvious mistake, but sad reality.)
